# Reference request: Spectrum of intersection matrices

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, matrices, terminology, spectral-graph-theory

Let $P(A)$ be the set of all **non-empty proper** subsets of a finite set $A$. Let $M$ be a matrix indexed by the set in $P(A)$ whose $ij$ the entry is $1$ if the associated sets are disjoint and $0$ otherwise. I have the following questions:

1. Whether the spectrum of the matrix $M$ is discussed in the literature? If so kindly share some references.
2. Is there a name for the matrix $M$ in the literature?

Thank you.

Comment: It feels more natural to allow $\emptyset$ and $A$, so $M$ has order $2^{|A|}$.
For example, when $|A|=6$ the characteristic polynomial factors as
$(x+1)^{20} (x^2-3x+1)^{15} (x^2+7x+1)^6 (x^2-18x+1)$, 
with all quadratic factors splitting over ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{5})$; 
while the order-$62$ matrix without $\emptyset$ and $A$ gives
$(x+1)^{19} (x^2-3x+1)^{14} (x^2+7x+1)^5 (x^2-18x+1) (x-1) (x^4-11x^3-64x^2-11x+1)$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Adding two more rows and columns will change the spectrum. I need the spectrum of M given in the question. It is a $(2^{|A|}-2) \times (2^{|A|}-2)$ matrix. Can you please tell me how did you calculate the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: in **gp**, the code 
**v = vector(64,n,binary(n+63)); M = matrix(64,64,i,j,v[i]*v[j]~ == 1);
factor(charpoly(M))** produces the first factorization, and
**v = vector(62,n,binary(n+64)); M = matrix(62,62,i,j,v[i]*v[j]~ == 1);
factor(charpoly(M))** produces the second.  Likewise for other $|A|$.

Comment: The order $2^{|A|}$ matrix is the $|A|$-th tensor power of $({1\;1\atop1\;0})$,
which explains its spectrum and the connection with the golden ratio.
Removing the first and last column and the first and last row
seems to decrement most of the multiplicities
by $1$ and to and create a new factor of degree $|A|-1$,
which has a factor of $x-1$ when $|A|$ is even.
The details can probably be worked out starting from the $2^{|A|}$ spectrum.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thank you. I will workout the theory part. By the way, gp means gap?

Comment: You're welcome.  No, **gp** is not GAP (the near-coincidence of names feels like a "birthday paradox" situation); see https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/ and 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARI/GP .

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the original question, just an answer to the question in the comments about "how did you calculate the characteristic polynomial?", which I couldn't fit into a comment.

Actually, I don't know how NoamD.Elkies computed it, but it is easy enough to do in SageMath.

```
size = 6
vertices = [s for s in Subsets(range(size)) if len(s) > 0 and len(s) < size]
g=Graph([vertices, lambda x,y: len(x.intersection(y))==0])
print(g.characteristic_polynomial().factor())
```

After selecting the size of $A$ to be 6, we proceed to

- declare the vertex set to be all the subsets of {0,1,2,..,5} that do not have size 0 or 6
- create a graph whose vertex set is this list of subsets, and where two subsets are adjacent if their intersection has size 0
- Ask SageMath to compute the characteristic polynomial and factor it.

Put this in a loop, and you can do a whole bunch of them (in this case from $|A|=3$ to $|A|=10$.

$
(x^{2} - 2x - 1) \cdot (x^{2} + x - 1)^{2}
$

$
(x + 1) \cdot (x - 1)^{5} \cdot (x^{2} - 5x + 1) \cdot (x^{2} + 3x + 1)^{3}
$

$
(x^{2} + 4x - 1)^{4} \cdot (x^{2} - x - 1)^{9} \cdot (x^{4} - 7x^{3} - 16x^{2} + 7x + 1)
$

$
(x - 1) \cdot (x + 1)^{19} \cdot (x^{2} + 7x + 1)^{5} \cdot (x^{2} - 3x + 1)^{14} \cdot (x^{4} - 11x^{3} - 64x^{2} - 11x + 1)
$

$
(x^{2} + 11x - 1)^{6} \cdot (x^{2} - 4x - 1)^{20} \cdot (x^{2} + x - 1)^{34} \cdot (x^{6} - 20x^{5} - 166x^{4} + 318x^{3} + 166x^{2} - 20x - 1)
$

$
(x + 1) \cdot (x - 1)^{69} \cdot (x^{2} + 18x + 1)^{7} \cdot (x^{2} - 7x + 1)^{27} \cdot (x^{2} + 3x + 1)^{55} \cdot (x^{6} - 34x^{5} - 458x^{4} + 2242x^{3} - 458x^{2} - 34x + 1)
$

$
(x^{2} + 29x - 1)^{8} \cdot (x^{2} - 11x - 1)^{35} \cdot (x^{2} + 4x - 1)^{83} \cdot (x^{2} - x - 1)^{125} \cdot (x^{8} - 54x^{7} - 1413x^{6} + 9288x^{5} + 17840x^{4} - 9288x^{3} - 1413x^{2} + 54x + 1)
$

$
(x - 1) \cdot (x + 1)^{251} \cdot (x^{2} + 47x + 1)^{9} \cdot (x^{2} - 18x + 1)^{44} \cdot (x^{2} + 7x + 1)^{119} \cdot (x^{2} - 3x + 1)^{209} \cdot (x^{8} - 87x^{7} - 4047x^{6} + 42186x^{5} + 205690x^{4} + 42186x^{3} - 4047x^{2} - 87x + 1)
$

Comment: @Gordan Royle. Thank you very much. The coding is very helpful for my calculations.

Comment: @GA316 Here is another piece of the puzzle: the partition of the subsets of $A$ into those of size 1, size 2, ... , size n-1 is an equitable partition. The quotient matrix with respect to this partition is an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix with the $(r,s)$-entry equal to Binomial($n-1-r$,$s$). The characteristic polynomial of this matrix contributes the high-degree factor in each of expressions above.  For example, for $n=10$, this matrix has char poly equal to $(x - 1) \cdot (x^{8} - 87x^{7} - 4047x^{6} + 42186x^{5} + 205690x^{4} + 42186x^{3} - 4047x^{2} - 87x + 1)$.